# Why was my answer spam, even though it included a disclaimer of affiliation? Can it be undeleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, spam, specific-answer

I answered this question: [How to perform Auto crop for document Recognize image using camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679768/how-to-perform-auto-crop-for-document-recognize-image-using-camera).

However, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679768/how-to-perform-auto-crop-for-document-recognize-image-using-camera/59209627#59209627) was deleted by a moderator:

You can also use online API's to do the cropping if that is an option.

> Xesario.com provides an API which can automatically crop and orient an
>   image. You can find the details of the complete api [here](https://xesario.com/api). The
>   specific api call that you are looking for can be found [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8283604/SVYkxhQy?version=latest#aa6588e0-e906-4008-b58c-e1dadc90ad60). 
>   There is a free tier so that might help you try out a bit or use it
>   for longer if usage isnt that frequent.
>
> Even though Xesario uses a custom built neural net to do the cropping,
>   we have found that the Hough Transform approach to be the most robust
>   algorithm out there which works without a neural net.
>
> Disclaimer: I work for Xesario.

I tried to make sure that the answer was helpful, and I even added a disclaimer to a conflict of interest, as I understand that this is required by [site policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

I do not understand why my answer was deleted. What can I do to improve my answer so that it can be undeleted?

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it only promotes the service, it doesn't provide a solution in the question on how to use said software to do it. Posts that only exist to promote a service against against the terms of the site.

Comment: Fair enough. So if I would have enumerated the specific api code to use, would that been ok ? Thanks.

Comment: @vicxtor I don't know what you mean by "enumerated", but an answer that has a fully fledged out code solution in it definitely lands a whole lot better, for sure.

Comment: Even with an actual solution, it would still require a disclosure of interest in the *body of the answer itself*, not in your profile, on the site linked to, or implied via your username. Some people still dislike affiliated answers and will downvote anyway, but at that point it's not spam and could be allowed to remain.

Comment: The original answer contained a disclaimer at the bottom, @Columbia. "Disclaimer: I work for Xesario." That is sufficient. (I'm telling you this because I know that, as a <10k rep user, you cannot *see* the deleted answer.)

Comment: A disclaimer is necessary but not sufficient to make an answer not spam.

Answer (score 15):

I think you missed the part about [self promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

> **Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much**. Folks will read your answers for their ability to solve a specific problem; if you're good at doing that, then they'll find themselves more interested in who you are and what you're working on. If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.

You did disclose your affiliation, but your post was still to promote your paid API service. As such, it was flagged as spam.